# WooCommerce - 1 (One) product in 2 (two) categories with different price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have two main categories i.e. Buy and Rent, and both having the same products. Now I want to show different prices for the buy category and a different one for the rent category for all products. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the prices differently in woocommerce for different categories. You really have a few options:

1. Don't make rent and buy categories. Make them attributes or variations on products and use conditionals.
2. Use hooks at pretty much every stage of checkout to adjust the pricing based on a cookie or temp variable. This will be a nightmare for reporting.
3. Make separate products. You can use hooks to update the inventory levels on the sale/rental of the offsetting product if total inventory is an issue.